# Make div disappear when on small screens?

Tags: html, css

My website has an overall CSS file, together with many inherited CSS files for different screen sizes.

In the overall CSS file **style.css**, I have

```
.image img {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

In my HTML file, I have

```
<div class="image">
   <img src="me.jpg"/>
</div>
```

When on a small screen, I want this image `div` to disappear, as I want people on small screens (e.g., phones) to focus on text only.

To this end, I added the following block to `style-xsmall.css`

```
.image img {
    width: 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

How do I make this image `div` disappear when on small screens?

Comment: The comma is invalid for CSS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .image {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

in this example everything that have "image" as class name will disappear on screen less than 300px, you can adapt for your case, it's only a example, you can set another screen size and css selector

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the right way to go, but when I append this code snippet after my `.image img { ... }` block in `style.css`, nothing happens.

Comment: I make this example for you: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGQOgG
as you can see, the width element depends on the size screen, problaby your css selector is wrong ou the way you are using it, feels free for share your code with me
see more about media query: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Thanks so much for the demo! It works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to fix this, use a media query. A media query will change different tags and sizes based on the absolute width of the screen that the user is using.